# why Response.redirect(url, false) throws exception as the site usage grows?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why response.redirect cause the error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829429/why-response-redirect-cause-the-error)

In my site, i have used the method `Response.Redirect(url, false)`. 
This runs well when there is no load in the site. But as the peak time arrives, it throws the exception. Why `Response.Redirect` throws exception as the site usage goes high?

The exception that is shown is `Thread was being aborted.`. I cannot reproduce this error in my local. It is only thrown in live when the usage is high.

Probable cause may be it passes through pages where the calculations of data is done, saved into database and again passes into another page where the data is displayed. And both times I have used `Response.Redirect(url, false)` to pass through the pages.
This normally takes 20-30 seconds for the final page to display. 
But at the time of exception occurrence, the request only process for about 10 seconds. It is spinning my head around.

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: @AVD, definitely not dup of that one - `Redirect(url)`/`Redirect(url,true)` do throw ThreadAbort non-conditionally, this is something else (if actual exception info is posted we can reason what it is).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the Response.Redirect that fails, but the completion of the request for the target page - which would have failed if you had opened it in a browser normally.

You need to investigate where the bottleneck is in your site.